# Expression manipulation for calculus in julia

Tags: julia

I am currently trying some functionalities of Julia regarding symbolic expressions. Coming from Matlab I searched the documentation for *symbolic* something with little success until I found some info about the `expr = :(<content>)` notation.

I started with the declaration of my first function : `fun1 = :(1-x)` which works fine. However, I need to reuse my expression or manipulations of it afterwards.

After searching a bit, I still did not find a way to say e.g `fun2 = -fun1`. How does one manipulate expressions once they are declared?

**EDIT** My example statement being a bit restrictive, an additional case would be the construction of a array of expression using pre-declared expresions as in `exprarray = [fun1 0 -2*fun2+3]`

Comment: Given the title of your question, are you aware that you don't need to manipulate expressions if your goal is to perform differentiation? See ForwardDiff.jl and Zygote.jl.

Comment: @tholy. Well to be honest, I am very new to julia. I tried the calculus tools for some small finite element computations with julia, where I need to be able to differntiate or integrate interpolation polynomials. If you have some advice, I'm all ears (or eyes) ;)

Comment: I can't comment on your specific application. Try the examples in those packages and then create a few similar examples of your own; once you see that working, you'll have a better sense of whether it's a specific problem of the finite-element computations or a more general problem with your understanding of how to use these tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can interpolate expressions with `$`:

```
julia> fun1 = :(1-x)
:(1 - x)

julia> fun2 = :(-$fun1)
:(-((1 - x)))
```

**EDIT**

The same works for the array :

```
julia> exprarray = :([$fun1 0 -2*$fun2+3])
:([1 - x 0 -2 * -((1 - x)) + 3])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I knew it worked for strings, but I think I undervalued the link between strings and expressions as in matlab symbolic math and strings are very dufferent things. Would you have a look at my edit ? What would be the correct way for  the declaration of `exparray` ?

Comment: I added it in the answer

Comment: Thanks. The solution on the array works fine, except Ican't differentiate it, even with broadcasting. What am I missing ? For instance with `dexp = differentiate.(exprarray,:x)`